# Attempt to insert non-property list object

Tags: swift, исключения

Есть структура

```
struct Items {
    let photo: UIImage
    let descriptionText: String
```

```
init(photo: UIImage, descriptionText: String) {
    self.photo = photo
    self.descriptionText = descriptionText
}
```

}
Хочу вставить фото из PhotoLibrary в массив

```
var items:[Items] = []`
```

В результате чего получаю такое исключение:

```
2019-07-03 21:58:59.681860+0600 WASH![13610:1879078] [User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object (
    "WASH_.Items(photo: >, descriptionText: \"eeeee\")"
) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key data
2019-07-03 21:58:59.685969+0600 WASH![13610:1879078] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "WASH_.Items(photo: >, descriptionText: \"eeeee\")"
) for key data'
```

Помогите
, пожалуйста, исправить проблему

Comment: У ва ошибка с сохранением объекта в UserDefaults, вы пытаетесь сохранить объект Items ?

Comment: Да, пытаюсь сохранить объект Items

Comment: Вы вопрос не о том задаете. Вам надо не про ошибку спрашивать, а как правильно сохранять свои модели в UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сохранить свою кастомную модель в UserDefaults, это нельзя сделать в лоб так просто.По умолчанию сохранять в UserDefaults можно объекты стандартных классов (String, Bool, Int и.т.п), и то там надо перегонять большую часть типов в NSNumber. Кастомные классы для сохранения должны реализовывать интерфейс NSCoding.

Вот пример реализации.

```
@objc(Language)
class Language: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var shortIndex: String?
    var languageName: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(withShortIndex shortIndex: String, andLanugageName languageName: String) {
        super.init()
        self.shortIndex = shortIndex
        self.languageName = languageName
    }

    // MARK:Serialization via UserDefaults
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.shortIndex, forKey: "shortIndex")
        aCoder.encode(self.languageName, forKey: "languageName")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        self.shortIndex = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "shortIndex") as? String
        self.languageName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "languageName") as? String
    }

    // Implement Equatable
    static func ==(lhs:Language, rhs:Language) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.shortIndex == rhs.shortIndex && lhs.languageName == rhs.languageName)
    }
}
```

Пример обращения:

```
let encodedLanguageFrom = defaults.object(forKey: "defaultLanguageTranslateFrom") as? NSData

        if (encodedLanguageFrom != nil)
        {
            let lang = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedLanguageFrom! as Data) as? Language
            if (lang != nil)
            {
                defaultLanguageTranslateFrom = lang;
            }
        }
```

Пример записи:

```
let encodedLanguageTranslateFrom = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: defaultLanguageTranslateFrom!)
defaults.set(encodedLanguageTranslateFrom, forKey: "defaultLanguageTranslateFrom")
```

Comment: та же самая ошибка остается